# How to read large text file stored in S3 from sagemaker jupyter notebook?

Tags: amazon-s3, text, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a large (25 MB approx.) CSV file stored in S3. It contains two columns. Each cell of the first column contains the file references and each cell of the second column contains a large(500 to 1000 words) body of the text. There are several thousand rows in this CSV.

I want to read it from `sagemaker jupyter notebook` and save it as a list of strings in memory. And then I shall use this list in my NLP models.

I am using the following code:

```py
    def load_file(bucket, key, sep=','):
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        obj = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
   
        text = open(data)
        string_io = StringIO(data) 
        return pd.read_csv(string_io, sep=sep)
```

```py
    file = load_file("bucket", 'key',sep=',')
```

I am getting the following error:

---

> OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:

Answer (score 1):

25MB is relatively small so you shouldn't have any problem with that. There are a number of different methods that you can use within a SageMaker Notebook instance. Since a SageMaker Notebook has an AWS execution role, it automatically handles credentials for you. This makes using the aws cli easy. This example will copy the file to your local system for the notebook and then you can access the file locally (relative to the notebook):

```
!aws s3 cp s3://$bucket/$key ./
```

You can find other examples of ingesting data into SageMaker Notebooks in both Studio and notebook instances in [this tutorial hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/ingest_data/012_Ingest_text_data_v2.ipynb).